# Could not load file or assembly 'RevitAPI' Error in Vscode using Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, plugins, revit-api, autodesk

I am trying to build my first Revit plugin in Vs code using python but unable to import any Autodesk  Packages, I am facing the below error can anyone please help me in resolving these issues.  I have followed [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88zIQCZw8BA) for installing the required Tools.  Thanks in Advance.

Here is my codes:

```
import clr  
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')  
import Autodesk  
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *  
print('success')
```

Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundException
Could not load file or assembly 'RevitAPI' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'RevitAPI'
**Please Note that I have successfully installed the Autodesk packages using command in vscode terminal:**
**pip install clr
pip install Autodesk
pip install Revit**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are two solutions:

1 Set the Environment Variable Path for the folder where your RevitAPI is.

2 Add the following codes:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\path\of\your\file")
```